# Using JS extension by default in module import in typescript

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I am trying to import a typescript module into another file using system.js but I have to specify the js extension at the time of import.

This is my app.ts file

```
import {PI, calculateCircumference} from "./math/circle.js";
console.log(PI);
console.log(calculateCircumference(10));
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning Typescript</title>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    System.import('/app.js');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to use the following code in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning Typescript</title>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    System.config({
        baseURL : '/',
        defaultJSExtensions : true
    });
    System.import('/app.js');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

TypeError: System.config is not a function

Where am I going wrong?

This is my packages.json file

```
{
  "name": "typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "lite-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "systemjs": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: I think `System.config` is only supported in SystemJS version 0.x and you are using SystemJS 2.x.

Comment: So what is to be done if js extension is to be made default. What is the new way of doing it?